# Unexpected Resolve is not a function

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have this function and I want to await for it like this:

```
await triesPlay(blobSource, reference);
```

But unexpectedly it returns an error when reaching `triesPlayResolve();` inside this if statment:

```
if(consecutive(exist)) {
   report.consecutiveTried.push([reference, c]);
   triesPlayResolve(); // reaching this produces the error
   return;
}
```

Here is the error:

[image]

And Here is the function:

```
function triesPlay(blobSource, reference) {
    let triesPlayResolve;
    int();
    async function int() {
        for(let c = 0; c < options.maxTry; c++) {
            if(consecutive(exist)) {
                report.consecutiveTried.push([reference, c]);
                triesPlayResolve();
                return;
            }
            await proccess();
            function proccess() {
                let proccessResolve;
                int();
                async function int() {
                    await Recognize(blobSource);
                    if(speechResult.simplify() === '') {
                        int();
                        return;
                    }
                    saveExpect(speechResult.simplify(), reference);
                    primaryExpects.push(speechResult.simplify());
                    proccessResolve();
                }
                return new Promise(resolve => { 
                    proccessResolve = resolve;
                });
            }
        }
        report.maxTried.push(reference);
        triesPlayResolve();
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
        triesPlayResolve = resolve;
    });
}
```

It dosn't make any sense for me!! how can I fix this? and why this is happening?!

Comment: why are you trying to get the `resolve` callback outside of the context of the `Promis` - your ode definitely needs a refactor as its really hard what you need it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function *before* your `new Promise` instantiation at the end of the function initialises the variable.

But all of this is totally unnecessary - `async function`s work that way out of the box, they always return an implicit promise that is resolved when the code in the function body `return`s, even (or: especially) after an `await`. You don't need any of those internal helper functions.

So you can simplify to

```
async function triesPlay(blobSource, reference) { /*
^^^^^ */
    for (let c = 0; c < options.maxTry; c++) {
        if (consecutive(exist)) {
            report.consecutiveTried.push([reference, c]);
            return;
//          ^^^^^^^ this is enough!
        }

        while (speechResult.simplify() === '') {
            await Recognize(blobSource);
        }
        saveExpect(speechResult.simplify(), reference);
        primaryExpects.push(speechResult.simplify());
    }
    report.maxTried.push(reference);
}
```